# how to keep a part of rows within a file based on information in a second file?

Tags: linux, grep, perl, cut

I have a data file looks like :

```
file1:

c1.212 3.4 90
c1.011 4.4 33
c2.09432 7.7 76
c3.0911 8.3 83
c3.1121 4.3 23
c3.2223 2.2 22
c3.1211 2.2 12
c4.1211001 1.2 11
c4.1111222 1.2 10
c4.0000011 99 76
c5.123 11 01
c5.113 11 01
...
```

and the second file looks like:

```
c1.212
c3.2223
c3.0911
c5.113
...
```

as you see in file 1 based on information in the first column, there are 5 groups (c1, c2, c3, c4 and c5) and each gruop has different number of subsets( for example c1 has 2 subsets but c2 has one subset), but in the second file there are 3 groups(c1, c3 and c5). What I want is if any group that is observed in file2, to remain in file 1 with all its subsets and those groups wich are not observed in file 2 (c1 and c4), to get removed from file1 with all their subsets. therefore the output should look like:

```
output:
    c1.212 3.4 90
    c1.011 4.4 33
    c3.0911 8.3 83
    c3.1121 4.3 23
    c3.2223 2.2 22
    c3.1211 2.2 12
    c5.123 11 01
    c5.113 11 01
    ...
```

Any suggestion would be appreciated.( the real file has more than 45,000 rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the good ol' `awk` staple

```
awk -F. 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} $1 in a' file2 file1
c1.212 3.4 90
c1.011 4.4 33
c3.0911 8.3 83
c3.1121 4.3 23
c3.2223 2.2 22
c3.1211 2.2 12
c5.123 11 01
c5.113 11 01
```

Or, assuming the group identifiers (`c1`, `c2` etc.) don't appear anywhere else in the file, you could use `cut` to extract the identifiers and then `grep` to match them in your first file e.g.

```
$ cut -d. -f1 file2 | grep -Fwf- file1
c1.212 3.4 90
c1.011 4.4 33
c3.0911 8.3 83
c3.1121 4.3 23
c3.2223 2.2 22
c3.1211 2.2 12
c5.123 11 01
c5.113 11 01
```

Comment: You should use `... | grep -Fwf- ...` in the first command, so that `c1` doesn't find `c10` etc.

Comment: @SatoKatsura good point, thanks - in fact I considered deleting the grep version after adding the awk one, but it had already been accepted

Answer (score 2):

Use `join` plus `uniq`

```
join -t '.' -o 1.1,1.2 file1 file2 | uniq
```

This will "split" each file on the "." character, and output rows that match by the first field. The "-o" option tells join to output only the first two fields from file1

You changed the question after I answered it, so it doesn't work now :) Use `sed` to pre-process the files to replace the first "." with a tab or some unique character

Comment: but the other columns changed and number of rows increased by this command! if you run this, you will see it output is not desirable.

Comment: @zara that's because you changed the question after I answered it! :) update coming...

Comment: yes but my real data is indeed huge and any kind of number might be observed in other coulmns such as 0.2 , 0.3 11.9. and I did not expect that someone might give an answer that a ' .' might make a problem. so i made a very simple example. sorry anyways :(